How to identify crawled property name for a column that exists in multiple lists?
I have few list and site collections.
They have a column, and the column with same name exists in other list and sitecollections.
Now in the crawled property how can I detect which column belongs to which list?

To identify the crawled property name for a column that exists in multiple lists, you can navigate to your tenant's Search Administration page and search for the crawled property name. The crawled property name will contain the site column's internal name, which is unique to each site column, and will be prefixed with "ows_". The crawled property name will also contain a four-letter code that represents the site column type. Different column types will have different naming.

How does it differ from other site column having the same name and type?
